# passing js string literal with html into component and retain html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, string-literals

I have an array of objects, where each object gets passed into a child component. One of the values of the object is a text blob as a string literal. This blob contains HTML links. I would like to preserve this links in the child component. Here is what it looks like...

```
`This is my text literal with a ${<a href="http://link.com">Link</a>}.`
```

I also tried creating a react object on the fly like this:

```
`This is my text literal with a ${React.createElement('a', { href: 'https://link.com' }, 'Link')}.`
```

This both rendered like this:

This is my text literal with a [object Object].

How do I get this to display the link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An untagged template literal (it's not a string literal) is evaluated immediately and results in a string. Within your template, you're creating a link element and embedding it in that string, so the `toString` method is called. You're seeing the result of the default `toString`, `[object Object]`.

You can't pass a template into a component. You could pass in a fragment containing the link:

```
<>This is my text literal with a <a href="http://link.com">Link</a>.</>
```

That's React v16.2+ syntax. If you're using something older, you may have to use `React.Fragment` directly (v16+).

If you're using something before v16, you won't have fragments; the usual solution then is a `span` or `div` (`span` in this case I'd say):

```
// v15 and earlier
<span>This is my text literal with a <a href="http://link.com">Link</a>.</span>
```

Comment: *(Sorry, if you see a backtick after the leading `<>`, hit refresh. Copy and paste error.)*

Comment: Oh wow interesting. Didn't know that. Worked perfectly! And most importantly, it still allowed me to break the text into multiple lines (this is required since it's a big text blob). This leads to another question, how does it work that react elements allow multiple lines 'out of the box'. Is that just how JSX works?

Comment: @MLeonard - Right. It's not that *react* elements allow it, it's that JSX does. More [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) (JSX isn't just a React thing).